# crawling nested pages using a single spider class and ItemLoader

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl through a webpage and extract a group of links then crawl through the webpages of those links and get the data by returning it through an item loader but having trouble. This is the code I have problem with in my spider class:

```
def parse(self, response):
   #--initialize selector--
   for s in response.css(SECTION_SELECTOR):
         #--populate object attributes--
         yield scrapy.Request( self.link, callback=self.parse_single )


def parse_single(self, response):
        #--initialize selector--
        for p in response.css(SINGLE_SELECTOR):
             #--populate item_loader (l)--
             yield l.load_item()
```

The problem with this approach is that only the items in the last `s` item are being returned, and the same items are iterated over and over when I save them as a `csv` file. The loop items in the second parse method are output as hoped with no duplicates.

If I try to switch the `yield` with `return` on the first parse method, only the first `s` item is executed, and again the second parse prints items to file as expected, but only the first `s` row is outputted with no duplicates.

Please someone explain to me how I can get the code to iterate over all the items in the first loop so they print in the second.

Comment: could you please share logs? Maybe some requests are being filtered, maybe they are duplicates, it's very hard to deduce this without knowing what you are crawling.

Comment: lease read [ask] and [mcve] and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: I fixed this by passing relevant values to the callable method using the request.meta array. I couldn't find how to do this before and was using the spider class attributes to assign and retrieve values in each of the parse methods, which evidently was causing problems. Thanks for the help :)